# How do I use a P7B file with Ubuntu?

Tags: ssl

Excuse my poor English and my ignorance about Ubuntu and Linux world in general.

I just received a `.p7b` file in order to connect with a private site through HTTPS. Using MS Windows, I just have to double-click that file and install it, but doing that with Ubuntu pops up a window where I could see all the details of certificate, then there were two buttons: "Close", that is the only one I can press, and "Import", that is gray and therefore useless.

So I searched around the Internet for a solution, then copied the `.p7b` file in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and ran `update-ca-certificates` with root permission. Nonetheless, if I tried to connect that site, Chrome gives me a `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`.  If I run againt `update-ca-certificates`, output is still the same it was the first time:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
7 added, 7 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Adding debian:Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.pem
Adding debian:GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.pem
Adding debian:RSA_Root_Certificate_1.pem
Adding debian:Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem
Adding debian:Thawte_Server_CA.pem
Adding debian:ValiCert_Class_1_VA.pem
Adding debian:ValiCert_Class_2_VA.pem
Removing debian:Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.pem
Removing debian:GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.pem
Removing debian:RSA_Root_Certificate_1.pem
Removing debian:Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem
Removing debian:Thawte_Server_CA.pem
Removing debian:ValiCert_Class_1_VA.pem
Removing debian:ValiCert_Class_2_VA.pem
done.
done.
```

Then I'm totally stuck... can you help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: [Related thread on serverfault.](https://serverfault.com/questions/417140/convert-from-p7b-to-pem-via-openssl)

Answer (score 3):

I have faced a similar situation, may be this helps. I have received a certificate in `.p7b` format. First, I converted it into `.pem` format. Then, I imported it into Firefox (or your browser). After that, I could access my application using that certificate.

Now, in order to convert a `.p7b` into `.pem` do as follows.

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in yourCert.p7b -print_certs -out yourCert.pem
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the certificate in your browser of choice.  In chrome, you can find this under advanced settings -> manage certificates -> import your certificate.

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work because Chrome (my version at least, that is the last update) only accepts PKCS #12 certificates, while it seems to be a PKCS #7 (whatever it means... I don't know much about SSL). I tried to convert it using: `openssl pkcs7 -in certnew256.p7b -print_certs -out certnew256.pem` but the result was `unable to load PKCS7 object
140670274774672:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: PKCS7` ... and then I'm stuck again :(

Comment: A p7 (certificate) is different from a p12 (key). You cannot convert one to the other.